# change the key "N" to on click by mouse

Tags: javascript

Good day, everybody, I have a simple question, I need help if somebody could do it, I'm trying to remove the key code "N" from the code and make the drawing by click on mouse on markers icon, I want the marker active by click on mouse without press "N".

I'm attaching part of the code

in html file :

```
<div class="panel panel-primary zeichnen-modus" id="panel-menu">
                        <div class="panel-heading">Add markers</div>
                        <div class="panel-body row">
                            <p data-element="recorderMode" class="col-md-5"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker" id="marker-indicator" title="Hold down the 'n' key and click on the map to place a new marker" data-toggle="tooltip">&nbsp;</span></p>
                            <div title="Set at least 3 markers to draw a polygon" data-toggle="tooltip" class="btn-sm col-md-6"><button id="zeichnen" class="btn btn-primary" disabled="disabled">Draw Geo-Fence</button></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
       keyCode = 78;

        $('html').keydown(function(e) {
                if (e.keyCode == keyCode) {
                    setRecorderMode(true);
                }
            });
            $('html').keyup(function(e) { 
                if (e.keyCode == keyCode) {
                    setRecorderMode(false);
                }
            });

            $('#marker-form').on('keyup', 'input', function(e) {
                var el = $(this),
                    val = el.val(),
        }
```

Comment: Not clear with your question. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: in this code the drawing will be start when user press in "N" from keyboard as mention in the code was set value 78, i want to remove that code key and the user will direct click by mouse on icon without press "N" from keyboard

Answer (score 0):

Change `keydown` and `keyup` to `mousedown`/`mouseup` and remove if statement

```
 $('html').mousedown(function(e) {
        setRecorderMode(true);
 });
 $('html').mouseup(function() { 
        setRecorderMode(false);
 });
 $('#marker-form').on('mouseup', 'input', function(e) {
       var el = $(this),
       val = el.val()
 });
```

Comment: thank you sir, could you please look into the code , i think there is something missed and need to change also , because after click by mouse the markers not showing , there is the code link https://ufile.io/2lzqy86c